# Screen Keyboard not working for Password Prompt and Show Applications Popup

Tags: 20.04, onscreen-keyboard

Recently updated Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, post that I am not able to use Screen Keyboard on Authentication Required pop up prompts to type password and also for Show Applications window.

As shown in image, Keyboard is rendered for Search in Show Applications. But on hitting keys using mouse on the onscreen keyboard it’s not getting entered in text box.

[Show Applications Search Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4tSs.png)

But onscreen keyboard works in Terminal, Browser and TextEditor windows.

Guide me in fixing this issue

Comment: I also have this issue. Only enter key works for login password which means on my media pc i need to plug in a real keyboard and get off the couch after pc locked screen.

Comment: @J.Reynolds i reverted the installed update to make it working.. now able to see the screen keyboard on login page.... shld be some issue with update or settings needs to update.... if fix found would be great so i can install updates..

Comment: Any fix for this ? It also affects the wifi password prompt.

Comment: @karel no fix found... i reverted the installed update to make it working....

Comment: I'm fighting the same issue. Do you have details on the "installed update" that you reverted to fix things?

Comment: Individual package update info I dont have as I reverted :(