# Unable to use onscreen keyboard for password entry. Does not register. Click-jacking protection? Can that be disabled?

Tags: 22.04, onscreen-keyboard

This is an update of this one from 20.04, which I guess hasn't been fixed so I want to add this for 22.04 and want to ask a bit more regarding it:  [Screen Keyboard not working for Password Prompt and Show Applications Popup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1304430/screen-keyboard-not-working-for-password-prompt-and-show-applications-popup)

So I recently got a "RasPad 3" which is basically a tablet-style case + screen for the Raspberry Pi and I've installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop version for the Raspberry Pi since it seems to generally handle a bit better for me (and is the better supported distro as a general whole) plus the recent interface changes that I actually hated at first, ironically, make it really good for a tablet layout (just horrible for a desktop layout IMO.)

So the problem even for 22.04 LTS is when a password prompt comes up, the onscreen keyboard is completely unable to respond at all.  (I don't even see the touched keys light up to indicate being pressed.)  I'm reminded of the SuRun software for Windows which provides something a bit more like the Linux password prompt and how it had an option to sort of block everything else to prevent "click-jacking" (I believe the idea being malicious software could otherwise simulate a click to force allowing administrative access without actual user input.  I think current versions of Windows already fixed this, but not older ones.)  Perhaps this is the same thing?  Eg it simply actually blocking passing through the input to the onscreen keyboard?  If so, is there a way I can adjust this to accommodate the onscreen keyboard?  Or, at the very worst, is there a way I can disable the clickjack protection?  At this rate I'm wondering if the only solution to this issue is to remove the account password entirely which is very obviously a very very bad idea...

Alternately, is there maybe just simply something misconfigured entirely that can be fixed?  I find it shockingly hard to believe anyone ever even actually tested the onscreen keyboard at all if they somehow never noticed you can never enter a password, so surely in their testing it must have worked, right?  So presumably it's something somehow different to this setup.  However, I don't believe it is specific to the Raspberry Pi build given that old issue was so exactly the same.  This is a fresh installation, so there are no settings to revert, however I have looked over every page of its settings and nothing has helped.  I really hope I'm just missing something.

Comment: This seems a lot like a bug. Did you look for a bug report on this issue? Developers use bug reports to track what they need to fix. They DON'T use AskUbuntu nor blog posts nor anything else. If the issue has been reported, then subscribe to the bug report so you can help test the fix and be sure that it's really an effective fix. If the issue has not been reported, then the lack of progress is unsurprising. Report it.

Comment: if you do manage to find a bug (or if you file one), please come back here to provide a link.

Comment: Also consider voting on this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kubuntu-meta/+bug/1973293 which prevents me from advising you to use kubuntu...

Comment: Well, I didn't really know how to search specifically for bugs other than searching places like this and of course the usual googlefoo in general.  I couldn't find a resolution or specific bug report, but I wouldn't be surprised if there is at least a bug report.  For now I'm afraid I have to give it up as I did have to switch distros (going back to Raspberry Pi os for now mostly due to better support from the manufacturer of the "tablet" hardware -- particularly the accelerometer.)  It doesn't even have an onscreen keyboard built in, but onboard seems to work a lot better with it at least.